# PHP script continues after closing / stopping page

Tags: php, exit

Seems php scripts continue even after closing or stopping a page.

for example, if my script is run by
/localhost/test.php

after I close the page, sometimes it continues to run.  I'm pretty sure restarting apache clears it out but is there a better way to terminate the php script after it's started.

Comment: You can use `die();` or `exit();` to terminate any function

Comment: True.  But I'm looking for something on the client side to stop the script.

Comment: Hm... how about a (GET) link to a function with an exit? All that comes to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [ignore_user_abort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) but I think it only applies if you are running PHP as a  command line script .

When running scripts from browser , in my experience I have realized scripts running even after the browser was closed . I did not go further to check how long they used to run .

The scripts that does huge processing that could run many minutes , I used to have control as below :

- A flag variable is considered which is stored in a database table .
- A way is provided to set the flag `On` or `Off` ( or `1` or `0` ) .
- The flag is checked in the script and the script is stopped running if the flag is found to be `Off` ( or `0` ) .

One way to consider the flag is in a loop as below :

```
while(true)
{
    /* Your code here which probably does lot of processing */

    if($flag === false) break; // Or exit if you prefer
}
```

If you have code that need to run following the loop , you would use [break](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) .
If you want to abruptly stop the script you could use [exit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) instead in its place .

Comment: ah!  that's really good.  maybe a tad inelegant but certainly solves my issue.  thanks.

Comment: No problem . I have PHP scripts that run in terms of minutes which are tested from a browser initially and later are set as a cron jobs . For my purposes I found it the best way to have control over such scripts . It's good that you found my answer helpful . Cheers ...

Answer (score 2):

check this out: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php

Sets whether a client disconnect should cause a script to be aborted.

Comment: the default is set to false (user_aborts are not ignored).  and yet it still runs.